# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autocorrect'

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, exe

trying to import a spell checker. My script works fine if i run it as python in terminal/pycharm. Have converted the script to an .exe with auto-py-to-exe and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autocorrect'
[10160] Failed to execute script 'search' due to unhandled exception!
```

even if autocorrect is added to hidden import: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A61Jx.png)

Also tried to import other spell checkers: pyspellchecker, hunspell, language tool and textblob. All give the same error except for textblob. If i use textblob my exe file becomes 1.2gb and have slow startup time. How should I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, some Python compilers have some problems with using specific libraries. I personally use PyInstaller (`pip instal pyinstaller`) with `pyinstaller {the filename here}.py --onefile` as command in terminal/command prompt.